Receiving messages from a pubsub subscriber, using pull vs using a callback
Using a GCP pubsub subscription, we are currently pulling messages this way:
    with subscriber_client:
        try:
            self.subscriber_future = subscriber_client.subscribe(
                self.subscription_path, callback=add_to_local_queue, await_callbacks_on_shutdown=True
            )
            self._periodically_process_messages(extend=extend)

The add_to_local_queue callback stores messages in a queue, and the self._periodically_process_messages runs a loop that processes queued messages, acks them if ok, then sleeps until the next 200ms tick.
The goal is to process messages in batches, for efficiency, but not wait for longer than 200ms.
This works most of the time. But I it seems the python pubsub library has its own internal queue of messages, so maybe this double queue management is unnecessary.  Maybe letting the library handle the queue would be a better approach.  This would mean fetching messages this way:
    with subscriber_client:
        while not completed:
            try:
                messages = subscriber_client.pull(timeout=0.2)
                self._process_messages(messages)

Here again, self._process_messages() would ack or nack messages depending on outcome.
Which approach is best ?  And do they both give the expected behaviour, i.e. process incoming messages by batches of 200ms ?
